# Interior of a set?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to think if their is any topology for which this is false:

If G is an open set, then G = interior(G)

Can anybody think of anything? I'm pretty sure it's straight forward.

Comment: It's true in any topology.

Answer (score 3):

From one of definitions, interior of a set is a largest open set contained in it. It means, that your statement ($\operatorname{Int}(G)=G$ for open $G$) is true.

Answer (score 3):

It's true for any topology, and the proof depends on the form of your definition of a set's interior. For example, one definition of the interior of a set $A$ is as the union of all open sets $U$ such that $U\subseteq A.$ Another (equivalent) definition is that the interior of a set $A$ is the unique open set $U$ such that for every open set $V$ with $V\subseteq A,$ we have $V\subseteq U$. (The latter definition is sometimes expressed as "[T]he interior of a set $A$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.)

Regardless of the definition, it is provable. If you have any trouble with the proof, feel free to let me know. (I *will* need to know what definitions you're using, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

By definition int(G) := $\bigcup_{U \subseteq G;\, U \text{open}} U = G$. In any topology.